# Pattern Class - Unsuccessful Match

Tags: match

Can you give me example about pattern class which can not match? Exactly, I need unsuccessful match with Pattern class. How should I find it out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following example to demonstrate the usage of Pattern class to match numbers only.

```
String NUMBER_PATTERN = "\\d+";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(NUMBER_PATTERN);

System.out.println("False validation:: " + pattern.matcher("123a").matches());
System.out.println("True validation:: " + pattern.matcher("123").matches());
```